# Installing jbpm 6.5 on tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, jbpm

I'm currently working on installing Jbpm 6 on tomcat 7.
However I can't find any guide on how to install jbpm on tomcat or how to link the components together
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can find quite detailed description how to install jBPM on Tomcat in [JBoss BPM Suite documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html/Installation_Guide/sect_the_generic_deployable_bundle_installation.html#sect_installing_the_generic_deployable_package). It is just productized version of jBPM and related project and the configuration should be similar.

Comment: what is a productized version ? and where do I get the sources , form the redhat website ?

Comment: [JBoss BPM Suite](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/bpm) is a product from Red Hat based on jBPM project. You need to pay for it but it is also available for free for development use. However, what I am saying is that you can follow the product documentation and with some modifications apply it on the community version. But I am not sure what you want to accomplish. Do you want to create your application with embedded jBPM engine or deploy KIE Workbench (jBPM Console) on Tomcat?

Comment: well both, I'm working on a custom app, so I will use the embedded jbpm APIs to work with the process and U I need the workbench too for administration puposes